# Window.open javascript function is not working in Mozilla, but working in other browsers

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, mozilla

Window.open javascript function is not working in Mozilla, but working in other browsers, here is what I have write.

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('../Terms.aspx','Terms','width=550,height=400')">
                click here</a>
```

Actually what happened in `Mozilla` is popup is opened but parent window is blank with `[object Window]`

Please tell me What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What, if anything, is logged in the error console?

Comment: The reason that the parent window is replaced with [object Window] is that the script is returning a reference to the window that is opened, and the string representation of that object is used as value for the href in the link. You could add `;void(0)` after the script to keep it from returning anyting which will keep the link from trying to navigate anywhere, but it's a bit cleaner to use the onclick event instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script looks all right, what might be a problem is that you are running it in the URL. Use the click event instead.

Also, you can use the href and target attributes in the link to make it degrade gracefully. That way the link will at least open up the page even if Javascript is disabled in the browser:

```
<a href="../Terms.aspx" target="Terms" onclick="window.open(this.href,this.target,'width=550,height=400');return false;">
  click here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [a generator](http://www.webmasterorbit.com/window-generator.html).

Alternatively, you might want to try `href="javascript: randomVar = window.open ..."`. The issue might be that the window.open function returns an ID, thus breaking the in-line JavaScript.